# Finding Prime numbers- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate a certain number(input) of prime numbers, only using "while" "for" and "If",etc statements. for example, if I input "8", the program should return 8 prime numbers 2,3,5,7,11,...and so on.

below is my code, but it only seems to give me 2 and 3, no matter what number I input.

Thank you so much for all your help!

```
num=input("enter the number of prime numbers needed:")
if num=='0' or num=="" or int(num)<0:
    print("No data ^^")
else:
    num=int(num)
    i=2; N=3; prm=True
    print(2); count=1
    while(True):
        if count==num:
            break
        i=2
        while i<N:
            if N%i==0:
                prm=False
                break
            else:
                i+=1
        if prm==True:
            print(N); count+=1
        N+=1
```

Comment: Are you setting `prm = True` for each attempted number (inside the outer *while*)? Any reason for the awful code style?

Comment: You can try `factor = lambda x: [i for i in range(2,x+1) if i %x == 0]` and `isprime = lambda x: True if factor(x) == 2 else False` for your prime detection code.

Comment: Please don't use semicolons like that in Python, even though it works. To do multiple assignments on a line, try `a, b, c = x, y, z`.

Comment: @Karl Why? (Assuming you do multiple assignments at all) Your suggestion seems much less readable.

Comment: It's considered more readable by the community; I don't always agree with the community, but I certainly do in this case. It also has the advantage of allowing for atomic state updates without temporaries (e.g. `x, y = y, x` to swap values). Raymond Hettinger goes over this at around the 34 minute mark in his excellent video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go

Comment: Also, from a DRY perspective, it factors out the `=` part of related operations and prevents you from having to write it more than once.

Comment: But where there are multiple statements that *aren't* all assignments (like `print(N); count += 1` it's recommended to just use separate lines. This isn't about conserving vertical space; it's about clarity.

Answer (score 1):

you just forgot to add `prm = true` at the end of the loop:

```
num=input("enter the number of prime numbers needed:")
if num=='0' or num=="" or int(num)<0:
    print("No data ^^")
else:
    num=int(num)
    i=2; N=3; prm=True
    print(2); count=1
    while(True):
        if count==num:
            break
        i=2
        while i<N:
            if N%i==0:
                prm=False
                break
            else:
                i+=1
        if prm==True:
            print(N); count+=1
        N+=1
        prm=True
```

Btw. The Code you wrote isn't the cleanest, maybe you should work on that

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help. This problem required me to only utilize basic level python (while, if, else, etc). would there be a way to make the code cleaner without utilizing other tools?

Comment: of course! What makes your code so ...unique is stuff like ```while True``` and then ```break``` inside the loop. You could do ```while count!=num:```.  And lines like ```print(2); count=1```, I honestly didn't even know that this worked in python ;-). But don't stress yourself too much, everyone started coding with bad code. Just keep going you'll do great!

Answer (score 0):

The intended logic is that for each candidate value, we start out assuming it's prime, then do each check to find out if it isn't.

Therefore, `prm = True` should be set at the beginning of each of the loops used to test a candidate value. In the existing code, it's set only once, outside the `while` loop. Thus, the first time that a composite value is found, `prm` gets set to `False` - and can never be set `True` again, therefore no more primes are detected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It runs a whole lot faster.

```py
factor = lambda x: [i for i in range(1,x+1) if x % i == 0]
isprime = lambda x: True if len(factor(x)) == 2 else False

num = input('enter number of primes : ')
if num == '' or int(num) <= 0:
    print('No data ^^')

else:
    num = int(num)
    primes = []
    for i in range(2, 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936):
        if i not in (2, 3) and i % 6 not in (1, 5):
            continue
        if isprime(i):
            primes.append(i)
            if len(primes) >= num:
                break

print(primes)
```

### Explanation

The `isprime()` function finds if a number is prime by checking if the number has two factors. The `factor()` function iterates through the numbers `[1, x]` and returns every number that has a modulo value of 0, meaning that it is a factor of `x`. ([`lambda` functions](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/lambda.html))

Then I loop through starting from 1 (the upper cap is `2^256`) and check if it is prime. A quick check is that a prime number >3 must be congruent to 1 or 5 modulo 6 (2,4 are even, 3 is divisible by 3) If it is I add it to the list of primes, and ONLY if it is, check to break from the loop. This increases the speed a ton.

#### Example output

```py
enter number of primes : 150
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863]
```

#### Timings

First 1000 primes: 1 second

First 2000 primes: 4 seconds

First 3000 primes: 10 seconds

First 4000 primes: 20 seconds

First 5000 primes: 33 seconds

By the way, 17389 is the 2000th prime.

Comment: wow, thank you so much for such a detailed feedback. This is so so helpful.